# Control keyframe animation progress via static interpolation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Given you want to control the progress of a CSS keyframe animation by manipulating the `animation-delay` property while `animation-play-state` is set to paused.

This **should**:

- work in [all browsers supporting](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) 
  the [CSS Animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/) specification
- run with at least 30 frames per second for basic use cases

For reasons motivated by render performance and proper separation of concerns you want it **not to**:

- require the script to know anything about the CSS properties interpolated by the controlled keyframe animation
- parse stylesheets to obtain said knowledge
- run the animation on a hidden element and transfer read interpolated CSS property values to the target element

#### Problem

The `animation-delay` technique appears not to work with the following browsers (problems can be reproduced in both provided examples)

- Safari >= 8
- iOS Safari >= 8
- IE >= 10
- Microsoft Edge

Is there any way to produce the desired behavior for all browsers while fulfilling all requirements outlined above?

#### Technique

- https://css-tricks.com/debugging-css-keyframe-animations/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4HdeJctq-A#t=26m53s

#### Examples

- http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/LVMMGZ/ (drag the slider)
- http://codepen.io/marionebl/pen/wKjBgQ (scroll down)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Control the progress of a CSS keyframe animation" ? What kind of control ?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is? What doesn't work about the fiddle you linked?

Comment: are you actually asking someone to solve your "Task"

Comment: @elio.d I just tried to find a good headline for the problem at hand. If you look at the provided examples you can see that I am the author of the second codepen...

Comment: @WalleCyril The examples should clarify your question

Comment: @DarkFalcon The provided examples do not work in the browsers mentioned under special notice. I tried to draft this question in a way that avoids pointing everyone into very specific cross-browser issues and keep the problem open for creative solutions

Comment: @elio.d Removed the offending word.

Comment: Keep in mind that we're not usually that interested in answering open-ended questions requiring "creativity" around here. We deal with specific problems and specific solutions to those specific problems. List the exact problem clearly in your question.

Comment: And include the reasons why the provided example does not work. For example, I can open it and it works fine on my version of Firefox. Tell us where it doesn't work, because we're not likely to go try to find that out.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: Moved the list with browsers where the technique does not work to its own section and outlined what the specific problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem

- the static interpolation technique [outlined by Lea Verou](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4HdeJctq-A#t=26m53s) does not work in browsers apart from Chrome and Firefox
- the specification does not cover the behavior of `animation-play-state` in combination with `animation-delay` unambiguously enough to call out IE and Safari for their deviating implementations. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-delay and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-play-state

## The solution

To partially cover the requirements outlined above I implemented [a library called jogwheel](https://github.com/marionebl/jogwheel) that allows for timeline control of animations declared via CSS keyframe animations. To achieve this jogwheel does the following:

- Get computed `animation-name` for a given `HTMLElement`
- Search `document.styleSheets` for matching [`CSSKeyFramesRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CSSKeyframesRule)s
- Transform the found [`CSSKeyFrameRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CSSKeyframeRule) to an array of keyframes compatible with the upcoming [`element.animate`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/05/Web-Animations-element.animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36), which is part of the proposed [WebAnimations](https://w3c.github.io/web-animations/) standard
- Provide an API that allows for control of the animation in relation to its timeline length

To use jogwheel you'll have to

**Install the library:**

`npm install --save jogwheel web-animations-js`

**In your JavaScript:**

```
// WebAnimations polyfill required
require('web-animations');
var JogWheel = require('jogwheel');

var element = document.querySelector('[data-animated]');
var wheel = JogWheel.create(element);
// Jumps midway into animation
wheel.seek(0.5);
```

Comment: A basic example of a bar to fast-forward and rewind an animation using JogWheel would be fantastic - there are no examples of this working that I can find yet :)

Comment: A crude example can be found here: http://codepen.io/marionebl/pen/rOEOZZ?editors=110

Comment: Nice! Any idea why it works in chrome but not safari? I'm looking through your JS to try and figure out exactly what isn't supported in Safari but I've turned up empty so far. That's awesome Mario, and really useful, thanks.

Comment: Some problem with the web-animations-js polyfill not loading, most likely an issue with codepen itself, I'm looking into this.

Comment: If it helps, I know there is `window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame`, and obviously all of the CSS `-webkit` prefixes. Have tried those.

Comment: @Jimbo I tweaked the integration of `web-animations-js` and published a bugfix release for `jogwheel`. According to my tests it should work now.